# GET via wget or cURL gives a limited response

Tags: curl, wget, http

I'm bumping my head on a simple HTTP GET request.

Using a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I'm getting the full and expected response (an over 1 thousand lines xml document, displaying the details of my 60 albums)

For this GET request, I provide:

- 4 parameters embedded in the url
- The default header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
- 1 cookie containing my session ID, to secure my identity

[image: Postman]

---

With using wget however, I get only a 505 lines long xml document. As far as I know, I do provide the same cookies, same parameters and header.

```
wget -o logfile.log -O response.xml --load-cookies cookies.txt https://app.viewbook.com/albums/?sort=date&order=desc&page=1&per_page=500
```

The "response.xml" I get is a well-formed xml document, but with only 25 albums, 505 lines long:

[image: Vim]

I was thinking there might be a built-in limitation within wget, so I tried with curl

---

Using curl, I get exactly the same 25 limited albums, 505 lines long xml response:

```
curl -D filelog.log -o response.xml -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -b "_accountservice3_session=ZFp6UU..." https://app.viewbook.com/albums/?sort=date&order=desc&page=1&per_page=500
```

---

I'm out of ideas why both wget and curl - while not totally failing - don't give the same complete result I get with the Postman tool.

Am I missing some parameters during my GET call?
Where does this limited length response could come from?

Comment: If you 8sed exactly the lines you showed, the **ampersands in the unquoted URL** are treated as terminating the first command and running the subsequent commands in parallel by all common Unix shells (and also as a terminator but run in serial not parallel in WIndows CMD, but that would give an error for the command `order=desc` etc).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm stunned! That fixed it! I forgot the ampersands has a special meaning in bash, and therefore I need to quote the whole url string. Putting the url into double quotes did fix my issue. I now have the 1000+ lines file I was looking for! Thank you so so so much. (you may add your answer so I can accept it). By the way, I'm not sure why I didn't get any error on `order=desc` as you said.